# Dictionary recursion to group keys by values

Tags: python, dictionary

I am wanting to group a series of dictionary keys based on values that model from and to nodes in a simple network and it seems like a recursive function would work but I am not having any luck.

Here is a simplified table:

```
ID   fromNode   toNode
a     1          2
b     2          3
c     3          4
d     5          6
e     6          7
f     7          8
```

From which I create the dictionary:

```
dict = {'a':(1,2), 'b':(2,3), 'c':(3,4), 'd':(5,6), 'e':(6,7), 'f':(7,8)}
```

The function result should be something like the following list:

```
list = (('a','b','c'),('d','e','f'))
```

because 'a' goes to 'b' and 'b' goes to 'c' and so on.

(PS I'd like to be able to solve this without using graph theory.)

Comment: How on earth do you expect to solve a graph problem "without using graph theory"?

Comment: Without using graph theory? it is a graph. Do you mean igraph package?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to get all the disconnected graphs from a dictionary representation.

```
def find(dic):
    graphes = []
    IDs = list(dic)
    while IDs:
        fromNode = dic[IDs[-1]][0]
        graph = []
        graphes.append(graph)
        findHelper(fromNode, graph, dic, IDs)
    # merge the broken lists
    connect = []
    for i in range(len(graphes)):
        for j in range(len(graphes)):
            if dic[graphes[i][-1]][-1] == dic[graphes[j][0]][0]:
                connect.append((i, j))
    if connect:
        for pair in connect:
            graphes[pair[0]] = graphes[pair[0]] + graphes[pair[1]]
        for k in connect:
            if k[0] > pair[1]:
                k[0] -= 1
            if k[1] > pair[1]:
                k[1] -= 1
            graphes.pop(pair[1])

    return tuple((tuple(i) for i in graphes))


def findHelper(fromNode, graph, dic, IDs):
    ID = ""
    for i in range(len(IDs)):
        idf = IDs[i]
        if dic[idf][0] == fromNode:
            ID = idf
            toNode = dic[idf][1]
            IDs.pop(i)
            break
    if ID:
        graph.append(ID)
        findHelper(toNode, graph, dic, IDs)
```

The above codes might work.

The above codes, while not all ids are enlisted, get an id from the dic and check wether it can find its way to another node: if so, they form a list and search for the next node; else itself forms a list. Then, it checks wether the already formed lists are split. For instance, for {"a": (1,2), "b": (2,3)}, in this stage, the code will produce [["a"], ["b"]]. The codes detect the situation and merge them to [["a", "b"]]. Finally the codes convert the lists to tuples and return.

P.S. The codes may contain bugs. Please point them out if you find them.